# Reading in text from a text file using java / jquery without a webserver

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html

I have used the jQuery.Get() as well as the $.Get() methods to do this but this does not seem to work.

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js" > </script>

    <script language="javascript">
    function Read()
    {
        alert("start"); 
        jQuery.get('/spec.txt', function(result) 
            { 
                    alert("get");
            if (result == 1) 
                {
alert("1");
                    $("body").html("<p>Specials</p>");
                    document.getElementById("specials").innerHTML = "<H1>Specials</H1>";
                }

else if(result == 0) 

                {
alert("2");
                    $("body").html("<p>No Specials</p>");
                    document.getElementById("specials").innerHTML = "<H1>No Specials</H1>";
                }
            });
    }
    </script>
    </head>

<body>

<button onclick="Read()">Specials</button>

<div id="specials">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to have a text file in my webroot folder that will only contain the values of 1 or 0. This will be used to determine if there are specials or not (this text file will be altered from another page). The value of this text file is to be read into the webpage and that will determine the course of action the if statements are programmed to. I have attached the code I am currently using to do this but I can't seem to get the $.get() / jQuery.get() to execute. You will notice I am using the alert() method to check the steps through the code but it does not execute the alert("get") immediately after the jQuery.get().

I am not using a webserver which I am assuming is the issue. I am simply running the index.html off my hard disk in the webroot folder. The IF statements are to fire depending on the value of read in from the text file named `spec.txt`

Please bare in mind I am new to web coding with jQuery and Java but I'm adept at simple HTML / CSS coding. This is my first attempt at dynamic web content like this instead of a static site. The site will eventually be hosted on a webserver if that helps with your answer.

Comment: Why don't you simply install a Webserver if you intent to run it on a Webserver later? With something like Xampp it's just 2 or 3 clicks away.

Comment: And what is your webroot if you don't have a server? Some folder named webroot?

Comment: And at last: you should be pretty happy that no one can write to/alter a file on your harddisk from another page without using a virus.

Answer (score 2):

You can't make ajax requests from file:// protocol. It's a security restriction.

Files loaded with file:// are always considered as coming from different domains, you can't bypass this feature.

But... If you are using chrome and just want to test it locally to put in a webserver later, you can disable this feature by running chrome in a unsafe mode

```
 path/to/chrome.exe  --disable-web-security
```

If you are using firefox. You can type in your URL **about:config** an then go to

```
 security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy -> false
```

It's ok for local testing only. Don't expect the users of your application to disable that as well or you will be **creating a big security problem**. Be aware you are disabling all browser security and it will be open for malicious program

Just install a simple web server and have fun!

Comment: You are right and i would vote your answers up. But don't you think its dangerous to give such advice to someone who has clearly no idea about what he is doing?

Comment: I think that as well. Anyway it's just an information. But I updated my answer to be more incisive about safety